Are covariance and contravariance asymmetric?
When I first learned some category theory, I was under the impression that covariant and contravariant phenomena were formally dual, and therefore had the same "value." However, as time has passed I have been exposed to a number of things which suggest otherwise.

Given a concrete category, a morphism is always monic if and only if its underlying function is injective, while the dual statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

More generally, forgetful functors are more often right adjoints, and contravariant functors tend to be nicer in practice.

Limits are generally easier to realize than colimits; e.g., the proof that Set is complete is almost trivial.

The Yoneda lemma only works when the represented functor is "in the left slot."


I suspect this all comes down to the fact that there is a preferred variance for Set, but I was wondering if someone wiser than me had a way of explaining these things; e.g.,

Is what I'm noticing legitimate, or just an artifact of what I am used to?

and if it is legitimate, is there a sensible source of this asymmetry?



I think the asymetry you are noticing comes from the fact that the category Sets is not equivalent to its opposite category. I might be wrong, but that is my gut feeling. (And the categogry Sets is of course fundamental to other categories through Hom functors.)

It is false that in a concrete category, a morphism is monic if and only if its underlying function is injective. In the category of divisible abelian groups, which is concrete, the quotient map $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a monomorphism.

The epimorphism is equivalent to surjective is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice is true in the category $\mathsf{Set}$. It is not equivalent to AC in an arbitrary concrete category. For example, there full reflective subcategories of the category $\mathsf{Group}$ in which there are nonsurjective epimorphisms between finite finite groups, so restricting to the finite groups gives you a concrete category in which AC holds but epimorphisms are not necessarily surjective.

Here is the discussion about the (pseudo-)difference between limits and colimits.

I have looked at site questions before posting this, but none of them addressed my concern. I do agree that I have not phrased my question precisely; I will try to narrow it and show evidence of research in a new post. Thank you for the feedback!

(I have removed my other comment because I think the tone was not good. Sorry for that. But I am looking forward to your edit.)
